# what is the exact meaning of "First LP value" in SCIP solver, for a nonlinear convex model

Tags: optimization, binary, scip

I have solved **using  SCIP** a **convex** mathematical model with binary variables, linear Objective function and a set of linear constraints amended with a single **non-linear** constraint making the model as a non-linear binary problem. 
In the output file provided by SCIP, there is a term named as:   **First LP value** and a value has been assigned to. I cannot figure out what is exactly the meaning of **First LP value** for my specific nonlinear problem ?? I appreciate any explanation in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For solving nonlinear problems, SCIP solves linear programming relaxations (LPs) that describe an outer approximation of the feasible region. The first LP value is the value of the optimal solution to the initial LP that was solved at the root node, after presolving, but before any separation.

Comment: I am gonna get the first LP value  just after the problem is presolved. So I called the cout <<SCIPgetFirstLPDualboundRoot(scip) <<endl;  just after the SCIPpresolve(scip).  The value reported by this function is different from the First LP val reported in the output file. May you please give me any clue? thanks

Comment: You are calling the function too early. After `SCIPpresolve()`, no LP has been solved, yet. Therefore, the function returns `1e+98` (aka `SCIP_UNKNOWN`), see src/scip/def.h. You should get a meaningful value dual bound value by calling `SCIPsolve()` instead of only `SCIPpresolve()`.